# Publishing a dynamic playlist through IIS Live Smooth Streaming

Tags: c#, iis, live-streaming, expression-encoder, smooth-streaming

I am publishing videos by using Expression Encoder with IIS Smooth Streaming.

I want to convert the system into a programmatic way. How can I publish my dynamic video playlist (which I made using WPF) via IIS Smooth Streaming? I have to make this playlist updatable and sync it with the live stream.

Can I do this with Expression Encoder SDK or IIS Smooth Streaming Format API? What do you suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @gheorghegu ,i'm also working in somethink like that, have u found a solution for this job